# Display Table-Cell And Vertica-Align Middle Not Working With Properties Set

Tags: html, css

I have a couple of divs that the content needs to be vertically aligned.

On my parent element I have `display: table` and on the children elements I have `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;`.

From what I read this should have been sufficient. For safe measure in my CSS I added heights to my elements to make sure they are both the same height as the parent element and I also added the image dimensions in the CSS to keep them the size they should be in case of failure to load.

I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0og1pszg/) of my code.

My HTML and CSS are both in the fiddle.
I figured it was easier to give a working example.

Comment: Take out the `float: left` in web-header-ad and it drops to the middle

Comment: Works. I take it that any element with a `display: table-cell;` automatically positions itself beside the other table-cell elements? I figured I'd have to float them. Mind putting an answer so  I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it.

Since you put it in a float, it is taken out of the normal flow

Setting `display: table-cell` makes the element act like a `<td>` element